# Unity3D list made of scrollview and buttons - how to delete item?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I have made list in Unity3D with ScrollView, Texts and Buttons.
When user clicks button near the item - the item should be deleted.
Buttons and Texts are created with Instantiate method.
The list of items is generic list (List).

List of items:

```
public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Creating buttons and texts:

```
public Button itemButton;
public Text itemText;
(...)
public void ShowItems()
{
    ClearItems(); //Destroys button and text gameObjects.

    foreach (var item in Globals.Items)
    {
        var text = Instantiate(itemText) as Text;
        var button = Instantiate(itemButton) as Button;
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Delete";
        textsList.Add(text); //save Text element to list to have possibility of destroying Text gameObjects
        buttonsList.Add(button);//save Button element to list to have possibility of destroying Button gameObjects
        text.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        //(...) Setting GUI items position here
    }
}
```

How to detect which item's button is clicked to remove the item?

I have no idea how to get that second button click == second item delete.

[image: List made with ScrollView, Texts and Buttons]

Comment: How are you creating the buttons and text, are you using OnGui or are you using Gui objects dragged in to the scene view?

Comment: it's utterly impossible to help unless you *include your code*.  note that if you are using the ancient "onGui" system, ***you cannot do that***. it is deprecated and no longer works.

Comment: I am using new GUI system. I have Canvas with ScrollView. The Texts and Buttons are created using Instantiate. I have no idea how to identify the buttons for ex. second button == second item.

Comment: Destroy(yourGameobject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one line of code:

```
        foreach (var item in Globals.Items)
        {
            var text = Instantiate(itemText) as Text;
            var button = Instantiate(itemButton) as Button;
            button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Delete";
            textsList.Add(text); //save Text element to list to have possibility of destroying Text gameObjects
            buttonsList.Add(button);//save Button element to list to have possibility of destroying Button gameObjects
            text.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            button.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            // this line:
            button.onClick.AddListener(delegate {Destroy(text.gameObject); Destroy(button.gameObject);});

            //(...) Setting GUI items position here
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @JoeBlow, you made me feel proud ;)